# TableView doesn't view value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode6

I have a TextField + Button + TableView in ViewController.

Project run, import OK. But I have to restart the simulator, TableView now show the value.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var myArray = [String]()

@IBOutlet weak var txtName: UITextField!

@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
    var delegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext!

    var newName = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Entity", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! NSManagedObject
    newName.setValue(txtName.text, forKey: "name")
    context.save(nil)
    txtName.text = ""
}


@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var delegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext!

    var export = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entity")
    export.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var exportValue = context.executeFetchRequest(export, error: nil)

    for ketqua: AnyObject in exportValue! {

        myArray.insert((ketqua.valueForKey("name") as! String), atIndex: 0)

    }

    self.myTableView.delegate = self
    self.myTableView.dataSource = self

    self.myTableView.registerClass(myCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    viewDidAppear(true)        
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    myTableView.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()       
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! myCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = myArray[indexPath.row]    

    return cell
}  

}
```

Comment: Update `myArray` and call `reloadData()`.

Comment: Independent of your issue **never ever call viewDidAppear()** – and all other delegate methods –  **explicitly**.

Comment: @vadian why is that?

Comment: The delegate methods are called by the operating system and conform to a particular order. At the moment the method calls super it can cause unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you should call the `reloadData()` after your data structure is done getting information/data, in your case after **inserting data into your array**.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
     myTableView.delegate = self  
      getMydata()     //<-- call the function here 

    }
     func  getMydata()
             {
               var delegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
               var context: NSManagedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext!

                var export = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entity")
            export.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

              var exportValue = context.executeFetchRequest(export, error: nil)
            for ketqua: AnyObject in exportValue!
             {
                myArray.insert((ketqua.valueForKey("name") as! String), atIndex: 0)
             }
              myTableView.reloadData()
        // and if you want use dispatch to get to main_queue again
    }
```

Comment: this would result in {exportValue.count}-times calling reloadData which reloads the table unnecessary often!

Comment: @Christian'fuzi'Orgler  my edit did not go through that's why and why did you negate the post

Comment: you posted invalid code. You did not set dataSource which will lead someone to try it out and have another issue then. Also you called reloadData unnecessary often. Edit your question and I'm happy to reverse my negation. (maybe you do too because I don't see why my code should fail?)

Comment: Hix hix. This not work......... I still must to restart simulator for TableView......

Answer (score -1):

I changed your code a bit and this should work for you. As vadian mentioned, you should not call viewDidAppear() yourself.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var myArray = [String]()

private var delegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

@IBOutlet private weak var txtName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet private weak var myTableView: UITableView!

@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext!

    var newName = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Entity", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! NSManagedObject
    newName.setValue(txtName.text, forKey: "name")
    context.save(nil)
    txtName.text = ""
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var context: NSManagedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext!

    var export = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entity")
    export.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var exportValue = context.executeFetchRequest(export, error: nil)
    for ketqua: AnyObject in exportValue! {
        myArray.insert((ketqua.valueForKey("name") as! String), atIndex: 0)
    }

    self.myTableView.registerClass(myCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    myTableView.delegate = self
    myTableView.dataSource = self

    myTableView.reloadData()       
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! myCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = myArray[indexPath.row]    

    return cell
}  
}
```

Comment: then I think something with your setup is wrong. Can you post more insight on this? How do you present it, are your outlets connected, everything is not-nil, how does your UI is setup?